# Golang: why *File instead of just File

Tags: pointers, go, underlyingtype

I'm learning Golang and I can't understand this API design.
So lots of os package methods return pointer to a *File.
My question is why is it a pointer and not just a value if File embeds pointer to a package scoped *file? Isn't it the same logic as for slices or maps? I mean, if its underlying structure is just a pointer to a "real" file object why can't I just pass it around as value? As I understand I would just copy File but underlying file won't be copied, only its pointer.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's for compatibility with old code. See [this version of the code](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/release-branch.r57/src/pkg/os/file.go#L16).

Comment: Pointers are nothing special and lots of things are used only through a pointer to it. There is no deep hidden secret going on here, the API is the way it is. As Cerise pointed out it has been "always" like this.

Comment: Just to clarify, the pointer type made sense when the `File` type had several fields. When the state was moved to an internal value to fix some issues, the pointer type was retained for compatibility.